# Nestjs: `yarn build` hangs forever on EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, nestjs

I have cloned my nestjs project on EC2 instance and when I run `yarn build` or `yarn start:dev`, it just hangs there and does not make a build.

Please let me know what are the possible reasons for this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using type free-teer-t2.micro, it consumes almost all CPU credits for a simple "yarn install" or "npm install" and then instance freezes.

It works well on higher types ( i.e., t2.medium and higher).